# Where to install dependencies for Quasar Capacitor Android project?

Tags: android, capacitor, quasar

I'm working a project that uses Quasar for the web app. That has typical folder structure with `

```
  package.json
  src
    App.vue
  ...
```

Now added an Android app compilation target using Capacitor. That added another folder called `src-capacitor` with it's own `package.json`

It feels that Android dependencies should be going in there as they will be used only in the app, but that means VSCode and bundler are complaining that they can't find those dependencies when they are used in the codebase. Solution to that is bringing them up to the `<root>/package.json`

I can't find any example projects that show where those dependencies should live.
Maybe it's stupid question, but please help me out here